# How to get the pandas DataFrame in this specified format ?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timetable dataframe like this :-

```
         subjectid  facultyid
day hour        
mon 1   4CCI02  5
    2   FR  42
    3   4CS01   39
    4   4MAT2   46
    5   4CCI01  29
    6   4MAT2   46
    7   4CCI04  47
    8   4CCI03  21
tue 1   MC03    48
    2   FR  42
    3   4CCI04  47
    4   4CCI02  5
    5   4MAT2   46
    6   4MAT2   46
    7   4CCI01  29
    8   4CS01   39
wed 1   4CCI01  29
    2   4MAT2   46
    3   4CCI02  5
    4   4CCI04  47
    5   4MAT2   46
    6   FR  42
    7   4CCI03  21
    8   4CS01   39
thu 1   4CS01   39
    2   4MAT2   46
    3   4CCI02  5
    4   4MAT2   46
    5   4CCI01  29
    6   MC03    48
    7   FR  42
    8   4CCI03  21
fri 1   4CS01   39
    2   4CCI02  5
    3   4MAT2   46
    4   4CCI03  21
    5   4CCI04  47
    6   4MAT2   46
    7   FR  42
    8   4CCI01  29
sat 1   MC03    48
    2   4MAT2   46
    3   4CCI04  47
    4   4CCI03  21
    5   4CCI01  29
    6   4MAT2   46
    7   4CS01   39
    8   FR  42
```

I want to group all this so that hour comes as columns and the subject and faculty come as the values for this particular day and hour ...

I want a format like this ...

```
              1       2       3        4         5        6        7        8  

mon         4CCI02  FR     5CS01      so on
              5     42       29

Tue         MC03
            48

Wed          so on
```

Is it possible to get a DataFrame like that format ?

What's the closest way to get the above mentioned view ?

I am using pandas library in python for the DataFrames .

Comment: At least a reason about the down votes is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index('subjectid',append=True).unstack([1,2])
```